# How to get a response for Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: php, facebook-ads-api

I'm integrating the API of Facebook Marketing, I tried to create a file to make some call, just to see if it was doing the communication. I created the following code.

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

$account = new AdAccount('XXXXXXX');

$params = array(
  'level' => 'account',
  'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::YESTERDAY,
  'fields' => 'spend',
);

$account->getInsights(array(), $params);
```

And the following message appeared:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount' not found in /var/www/html/ApiFacebookMarketing/index.php on line 6
```

Does anyone know what can it be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did `composer install` run successfully?

Comment: That was it and a little more, I had to clean my code. Thank you very much! @ishegg